# Limiting redis queue within a range

Tags: redis, queue

I am working on redis queue (lists). Push is parallel and huge, whereas pop is single threaded. My queue is growing rapidly and I want to limit it within a range. I can handle it at the reader thread, where I pop and process.

Now, my question is, is there any way to limit the list without exceeding a certain limit? For example, say 100 without the need of popping one by one. I want to retain the new ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Ltrim command in your reader thread.

http://redis.io/commands/LTRIM

```
Ltrim queue 0 100
```